# Why Alexa has two rankings for my website?

Tags: ranking, alexa

I have a website that has two different Alexa rankings as follows:

1) The public ranking on Alexa siteinfo page of the website, that is the usual ranking page and it indicates a rank of **318,254** which they claim it is updated daily.

2) Another public and daily ranking of the same website but it is viewable using either the freely available list for **Top 1,000,000 Sites** in this [page](http://www.alexa.com/topsites) at the almost top right **or** using [StatsCrop](http://statscrop.com) website and this ranking indicates a rank of **253,753**.

Which one is more accurate? Why different daily rankings?

Comment: I would say that maybe StatsCrop is just storing a more dated rank? I've tested my website and there's also a similar difference. I stopped following our Alexa rank some time back, it's wildly inaccurate.

Answer (score 3):

StatsCorp uses Alexa and does not have the resources that Alexa have at their disposal, because of this you the data is lagged and just outdated. When checking something you should always check at the source at not a third party, your rankings are more accurate at Alexa than Statscorp

*Alexa Who Cares Anyway?*

With all this said Alexa is extremely unreliable and not a true estimate of how busy your site is.... it is a mere calculation of how many people are using their toolbar, since Toolbar usage varies from niche to niche its terribly unreliable and the only stats you should interest yourself is actual 'unique visitors.

Comment: Would you happen to know roughly the usage of the Alexa Toolbar per browser? Our website has particular high browser requirements and we've been actively encouraging users to adopt Chrome and FF for years. I'm wondering if most Alexa toolbars reside on old versions of IE? Is it even possible to run an Alexa toolbar on Chrome?

Comment: Impossible to estimate, it varies from niche to niche, not only browser hence Alexa Rank is pointless and why should anyone care beats me because Actual Visitors is the only thing that matters, goals should be to increase 'actual foot flow' not Alexa rank....

Comment: I agree, although I think people use Alexa to make comparisons with their competitors, as a standalone analytics tools it's useless.

Comment: Those people have no idea how Alexa works ;)